# How do I loop a string if the answer to a question isn't valid until the answer is valid -python

Tags: python, windows, scripting, new-operator

I am completely new to scripting and I'm practicing on learning how to script in python. I want to know how to keep looping a string until a valid answer is input. For example if the input() string was a question like "Do you like cookies? Please answer with Yes and No." and they put "maybe", I would want it to say "Please answer with Yes and No" every time they put a different answer that is not yes or no. Every time I put a different answer to my string it will say it once and then say "maybe is not defined". Another thing I would like to know is when I put a different answer besides yes or no, it will print "Please answer with Yes and No" twice. It is probably an obvious mistake or find but I'm new to it all and barely know what I am doing. Thank you to everyone that helps and understands my issue. :)

Here is a stupid rookie example of my project.(It's not actually associated with cookies its just for the example.)

````
answer: input("Do you like cookies?")                           Do you like cookies?: Yes
x = ("I like cookies too!")                                     I like cookies too!
a = ("I don't like cookies either.")                            Please answer with Yes and No.
b = ("Please answer with Yes and No.")                          Please answer with Yes and No.
if answer == 'yes':                                                                                                                    
                      print (x)
                                              
if answer == 'no':                                              Output when I put no:
                      print (a)                                 Do you like cookies?: No                              
                                                                I don't like cookies either.
if answer != 'yes':                                             Please answer with Yes and No.                                    
                      print (b)                                 Please answer with Yes and No. 

if answer != 'no':
                      print(b)                                  Output when I put anything else:
                                                                Do you like cookies?: Maybe
```                                                             Please answer with Yes and No.
                                                                Please answer with Yes and No.
                                                                >Maybe
                                                                >"Maybe is not defined"
                                                                


Everything is explained.⬆️
````

Answer (score 1):

for a something relatively simple without the repeated need for input (in that case define a function) I like dictionaries and converting the input to all lowercase to match.

```py
options = {
    "yes": "I like cookies too!",
    "no": "I don't like cookies either.",
    "maybeso": "I only like chocolate chip."
}

while True:
    answer = input("Do you like cookies? ").lower()
    if answer in options:
        print(options[answer])
        break
    else: print("Valid answers are:", *options)
```

Answer (score 0):

The key here is entering into a "forever" loop and then using the `break` statement once you get the wanted input!

Here is how it would work using your example:

```
    # Keeps looping until user gives proper input
while True:
    # Asks the question and stores answer in variable
    answer = input("Do you like cookies?")
    
    if answer == 'yes':
        # Prints proper answer and leaves the loop, ending the program
        print("I like cookies too!")
        break
    elif answer == 'no':
        # Prints proper answer and leaves the loop, ending the program
        print("I don't like cookies either")
        break
    else:
        # Prompts the user to provide the proper input and loops through the program again (doesn't break)
        print("Please answer with yes or no")
```

Comment: This answer has a high probability of being AI generated. Please read Stack Overflow's guidelines on AI content: https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy

Comment: I wrote this myself? I can send you the vs code screenshot if you'd like.